# My css code is not working correctly, image is jumping around

Tags: html, css, image

I really having a hard time trying to figure out why my css code is not placing the image correctly. Every time I change my **screensized** the image is jumping from one place to another, so the image is not placed exactly where I want it to :(

The Css code I use is:

```
.reviewbox{position:relative; margin-top:-900px; margin-left:450px; width:711px;}
```

A live view is: http://dorchdanola-netbutik.dk/order/cart/

- You will see that the image is not placed under the white content box. Could you guys help me sort this out?

Thanks alot

Comment: I see no image that is jumping around on that page. Which image are you talking about? And which browser? And by 'screensized', do you mean the screen resolution, the window size of the browser, or something else?

Comment: By seeing the `margin`s you use it is very likely that something is going to happen on smaller screens. Why so much margin?

Answer (score 0):

Your image is not jumping around. It is just poorly placed.

Try to integrate the div into the 'flow' of the html. You are trying to place it to the right place by forcing it.

simple html structures work way better that exessive use of margin and positioning.

Comment: Hi Hauke, thanks for the reply. 

The image is being generated by a div that comes from a javascript. Since I dont have rights to edit the html. page I can only create the div by adding a Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the relative position is not the good way because it's depending to resolution and size of all element on your page ...

The best solution is to integrate the div just after your .cart

But if it's not possible, you can use jquery for add dynamically the picture after your .cart.

Try and adapt this code

```
$( ".cart" ).after( "<img src="xxxx" \>" );
```

Comment: Hi david, I dont have access to place the code on the order page, I have to insert the image from my header with javascript so when the url is equal to order/cart the image should appear

Comment: Ok then try the jquery code that I send in my first post.

Comment: Hi David, if I correct the code to this:
<code>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){ 
if(document.URL.indexOf("order/cart/") >= 0){
   $( ".cart" ).after( "<img src="http://dorchdanola-netbutik.dk/Resources/Files/Diverse/review-box.jpg" \>" );
}


    </script>
</code>

Comment: Maybe, it's your job to adapt the code ;-) but your syntax is good ;-)
But it's necessary to implement jquery librairies in your page. 
And it's necessary that your code "$( ".cart" ).after( "<img src="dorchdanola-netbutik.dk/Resources/Files/Diverse/…; \>" );" is executed in the end of your page.

Comment: Don't forget to validate an answer if you resolved your problem ;)

Comment: Hi David, unfortunately my problem has'nt been resolved yet :(

Answer (score 0):

David-IT is right, this would be the correct way to insert the div.

If you are using jquery, this would do the job (I dont think you even need the div):

```
var htmlDiv = '<div><img src="http://dorchdanola-netbutik.dk/Resources/Files/Diverse/review-box.jpg"></div>';

$(".cart").after(htmlDiv);
```

Comment: Ok so my code should be like this??
`<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){ 
if(document.URL.indexOf("order/cart/") >= 0){
var htmlDiv = '<div><img src="http://dorchdanola-netbutik.dk/Resources/Files/Diverse/review-box.jpg"></div>';

$(".cart").after(htmlDiv);
}

    </script>`